# Как понять, что пользователь ушел в спящий режим?

Tags: android, java

Как понять, что пользователь ушел в спящий режим, ну, типа на блокировку нажал?

Comment: Думаю, что на активити должно сработать событие onPause

Comment: На одном сработает, а у меня их несколько... слышал что-то про ACTION_+SCREEN_ON, может, знаете что про него?

Comment: @asdasdasd, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Надо ставить `BroadcastReceiver`, который ловит событие: `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF`

Декларация в манифесте:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">   
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

собсно сам ресивер:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {    
        Log.i("MyReceiver", "Bingo! Screen off!");
    }
}
```

**Update**

Здесь есть одна небольшая западня. Если продекларировать в манифесте с ключом `exported=true` (в данном случае он по дефолту `true`), то ресивер будет работать всегда (с момента установки аппы до его сноса) - то есть будет ловить бродкасты даже если приложение не работает.

Надо быть аккуратным с этим, легко можно нарваться на грубость со стороны системы. Более подробно об этом [здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)